# Payment Gateway | Local Fund transfer to bank

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, authorize.net

I am developing portal which requires sending automatic payment. For international payments I am already working on Paypal's adaptive API. But I want to know how to integrate local fund transfer, directly to users bank account.

I saw oDesk.com , they have pretty well system of sending funds through local bank accounts.

I want to know how they did that? Is there any merchant like authorize.net or something?

Initially the target will be users from India (who will receive payments), any idea if any bank provides some API for that?

Comment: Overseas bank transaction are cleared through Swift.  A bank where you have a merchant account will provide check clearing, wire transfers and bank to bank transfers. Some can provide APIs.

Comment: Authorize.Net does not offer this service.

Comment: @starbolin I dont want overseas bank transaction. I want local fund transfer. Like a bank in India will transfer to other bank accounts of users in India only.

Comment: Just curious,do u able to find any solution for that?

Comment: @DroidBot Only solution is to use payment merchants, like paisapay or zaakpay etc...

Answer (score -1):

google for "India Payment Gateways API". Also, have you tried to contact the Reserve Bank of India,  which maintain electronic transfer systems (ie NEFT), and check if an API is available for developers?

Comment: "google it" , I really dont like these answers. Obviously, thats the first thing everybody do to search relevant content!

Why would RBI provide that? it has nothing to do with RBI, the transaction will go through BANKS! Banks will deal with RBI, not me.